# Loop through matrix

Tags: lua

I'm creating a simple matrix like follows:

```
for x = 0, 50 do
  current_level[x] = {}

  for y = 0, 50 do
      current_level[x][y] = grabTile();
  end
end
```

After that i try to read it, but somehow the x is now a object not a number, while y seems perfectly fine!

How i try reading it:

```
for x,value in pairs(self.map) do
 if value == ni then print("none"); return;end;
 for y,object in pairs(value) do
   if object == ni then print("none"); return;end;
   object:render(x,y); -- Here x is an object
 end
```

end

I'm new to working with lua, so i might be doing something obvious terribly wrong.
How would i make this work?

What i get for x is something like: table: 0x07c8d530
This value stays the same along the complete iteration

Comment: Are you intentionally writing `ni` instead of `nil`? Tables in Lua can't hold `nil` values, so you won't ever get `nil` when you're iterating over them with `pairs`.

Comment: This code isn't printing anything. I'm assuming your `print(x)` was inside `object:render` -- can you include the code for that function, too, including the print?

Comment: @CurtisF the funny side is that it still work, because global variable `ni` is not declared, so reads `nil`. Until it is actually created and filled :)

Comment: @CurtisF No that was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> object:render(x,y); -- Here x is an object

This line is using colon syntax. It is a syntactic sugar for `object.render(object,x,y)` call.

So your `render()` function must have the first `self` argument declared either explicitly as `function render(self, x, y)` or implicitly with another syntactic sugar for definition: `function object:render(x,y)`.

Unrelated hint. The first loop will be faster/smaller if transformed to:

```
for x = 0, 50 do
  local row = {}

  for y = 0, 50 do
      row[y] = grabTile();
  end
  current_level[x] = row
end
```

Comment: That did the magic! Although i had to use render = function (object, x, y), because i didn't get the other one to work!